# I've made an eye using nodes which moves when a bone is rotated. Will it still function if I port it over to another software?

Tags: materials, node-editor, export

[image]

I'm attempting to make a Vtuber avatar and I want it to use this for the eyes. If I port it to another software, will these eyes still move with the bone or would I have to find an alternative method?

Comment: No. It will not work.

Comment: no, because (blender)-shader nodes won't work in other software

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541